# SimpleCursorAdapter to[] and from[] mapping with a content provider

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I have a `ListView` with 5 `TextView`s and so I am using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` to populate it. The data's coming from a content provider.
My problem is the with the `_id` column. I know I **have** to include it for the adapter to work. My problem is, I have 5 text views and I'll set the **projection** array for **six** columns.

### Arrays of to[] and from[]

```
static {

    from = new String[] {
        EmployeeProviderContract.ROW_ID,
        EmployeeProviderContract.F_NAME,
        EmployeeProviderContract.L_NAME,
        EmployeeProviderContract.ROW_EMP_ID,
        EmployeeProviderContract.AGE,
        EmployeeProviderContract.SEX
    };


    to = new int[] {

            R.id.employee_first_name,
            R.id.employee_last_name,
            R.id.e_employee_id,
            R.id.e_age,
            R.id.e_sex
    };
}
```

As you can see, I have 5 items in the `to[]` and 6 items in the `from[]` (because of the _id).

### The simple cursor adapter

```
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
    R.layout.single_row_layout, // The row template
    null, // Cursor but we dont have one right now, so NULL. Will come from swapCursor()
    from,// Columns to show from 
    to, // The layout ids i.e individual text views to show the data in
                0); // Default 0 as FLAG
```

So as a result, when the cursor returns, it sets the value of `_id` in the `R.id.employee_first_name` and so on with the rest of the values. I dont want to show the `_id` in the text views. I cant remove the _id otherwise it throws an exception. **How do I fix this ?** Very stupid problem but I can't seem to find a proper way.

This is what is content provider query looks like

```
Cursor returnCursor = db.query(EmployeeProviderContract.EMP_PERSONAL_TABLE_NAME,
                projection, selection , selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
```

*Note: I am extending `Activity` and not `ListActivity`.*

Comment: *I cant remove the _id otherwise it throws an exception.* what kind of exception?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

Comment: I see. In the `create table` query did you had the `_id` column?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the Cursor returned from the ContentProvider does not include an "_id" column. Check if your database table has an _id column. The best practice is to implement the **BaseColumns** interface in the inner class(table class) inside your Contract class, which is used by your implementation of SQLiteOpenHelper to create the database..